# Dependency injeciton vs global factory

Tags: spring, language-agnostic

Why do people default to DI vs a global factory with a hashmap that maps interfaces/abstracts to classes? It would seem this is a higher performance solution to the problem no?

All the things mentioned so far in this thread can be provided by a global factory with a method like:

```
TestGlobalFactory implements GlobalFactoryI
ProductionGlobalFactory implements GlobalFactoryI //configures classes to interfaces

protected GlobalFactoryI gf=GlobalFactoryFactory.getInstance(); //only singleton used in app, specifies which GlobalFactory to use

protected SportsCarI mySportsCar=gf.new("sportsCarI",constructorVar1,constructorVar2);
```

The above would be much faster than recursive reflection to detect DI instances.

However I admittedly prefer the convention of DI as it ends up being fewer characters and greater flexibility with the option of third party containers.

artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=238700

Regardless DI, is the superior approach as it has the containers written to specify which implementation belongs in which class. With Service Locator one would actually have to do gf.new("thisClass","sportsCarI",constructor1)

Comment: Please do not reply to this thread, as it would seem its a matter of preference.

Comment: no, it's not a matter of preference.

Comment: See question edit. Testability can be maintained as proposed. Regardless, DI constructor/setter convention is great as the above can be implemented with global factory and DI.

Comment: Your proposition is not type-safe, fails very late at runtime (because it's only when some dependency is asked that a failure will occur), and needs a custom global factory for each test. Try implementing a complex application, with unit tests, with your design, and then do the same with DI, and you'll feel the difference. The best explanation I've found of the advantages of DI is in this video : http://blog.crazybob.org/2007/06/introduction-to-guice-video-redux.html. It compares a factory approach with a DI approach.

Comment: http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=106&thread=238700 Regardless DI, is the superior approach as it has the containers written to specify which implementation belongs in which class. With Service Locator one would actually have to do gf.new("thisClass","sportsCarI",constructor1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main advantage of dependency injection over a factory-based approach is not performance. Its main advantage is testability. The whole point of DI is to be able to inject mock dependencies to implement the unit tests of a component. Doing it with a factory is much more painful.

Comment: +1. with DI your application code doesn't have to reference the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Because you get a lot more with Spring.  Spring manages the *lifecycle* of its beans, in addition to caching instances in line with the user specified scope for the beans (e.g. prototype, singleton, etc).  Also note that Spring's DI is related to its "Inversion of Control", so things are not hard coded directly into the app (unless you consider configuration code).